# array_intersect in java

Tags: java

I found this snippet online that made a array_intersect like function in java using integer.

Sample:

```
        int[] intersect(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
            int count = 0;
            for(int a = 0; a < arr1.length; a++) {
                for(int b = 0; b < arr2.length; b++) {
                    if(arr1[a] == arr2[b]) {
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            int[] result = new int[count];
            count = 0;
            for(int a = 0; a < arr1.length; a++) {
                for(int b = 0; b < arr2.length; b++) {
                    if(arr1[a] == arr2[b]) {
                        result[count++] = arr1[a];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        int[] arr1 = new int[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100,
         95, 85, 75, 65, 55, 45, 35, 25, 15, 05,
         10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55};

        int[] arr2 = new int[] {15, 25, 35, 45, 55,
         12, 22, 32, 43, 52,
         15, 25, 35, 45, 55};

        int[] p1 = this.unique(arr1);
        int[] p2 = this.unique(arr2);
        int[] intersectResults = this.intersect(arr1, arr2);

            for(int a = 0; a < intersectResults.length; a++) {
                System.out.print(intersectResults[a] + "    ");
            }
```

But when i changed it to:

```
        String[] intersect(String[] a_yourname, String[] a_crushname) {
            int count = 0;
            for(int a = 0; a < a_yourname.length; a++) {
                for(int b = 0; b < a_crushname.length; b++) {
                    if(a_yourname[a] == a_crushname[b]) {
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            String[] result = new String[count];
            count = 0;
            for(int a = 0; a < a_yourname.length; a++) {
                for(int b = 0; b < a_crushname.length; b++) {
                    if(a_yourname[a] == a_crushname[b]) {
                        result[count++] = a_yourname[a];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

     String[] flames = this.intersect(a_yourname, a_crushname);
            //String[] p23 = this.unique(arr2);
             System.out.println("heheh" +flames.length);
             for(int a = 0; a < flames.length; a++) {
                System.out.print(flames[a] + "    ");
            }
```

Can someone explain to me what I did wrong here? I'm really not familiar with Java.

`a_yourname` and `a_crushname` are both string arrays.

Comment: Are you using `==` to compare two strings? The cleaner and potentially faster method is to put one array into set and another into some collection (e.g. `Arrays.asList()`) and call `retainAll()` on the set.

Comment: @billc.cn can you give an example of that? i just got that code form the net not sure how that works :)

Comment: Putting Java code incorrectly in a JSP file instead of a Java class doesn't make it a JSP problem. You'd have had exactly the same problem when putting that Java code in a normal Java class with a `main()` method. I removed the non-related JavaEE/JSP noise from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
    String[] a = new String[] { "aa", "bb", "cc" };
    String[] b = new String[] { "bb", "cc", "dd" };

    Set<String> setA = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
    List<String> listB = Arrays.asList(b);
    setA.retainAll(listB);
    System.out.println(setA);
```

You can see the results here:
http://ideone.com/tKg5xa

If you really want the result as an array:

```
String[] out = setA.toArray(new String[setA.size()]);
```

Again there's no need to use an array if all you want is to iterate through the result. Google "Java for each" or pick up a Java book.

Comment: Why is there a new String[]? Is it necessary or is just a choice of declaration of array?

Comment: No, it's not strictly necessary in this case. It's just an old habit.

Comment: is setA returned as an Array?

Comment: No, it's a Set. Use `Set.toArray()` to get an array, but there's really no need to do that. Most cases Collections works better than Arrays in modern Java.

Comment: thank you for this it really works great, but regarding the code above do you understand most of it?

Comment: where do you exactly add this Set.toArray()?

Comment: You only need `toArray()` if you absolutely need an array (normally when dealing with other people's functions). Otherwise, Collections can replace Arrays in most use cases. If you were iteration through an array, you can replace it with Java's for-each loop.

Comment: i need to get the result and store it in an array since i need it in another loop. can you edit your answer to result an array since ive been trying and i cant get it. thank you :)